# Difference between http and default servemux?

Tags: go

What's the difference between this:

```
func main() {

  http.HandleFunc("/page2", Page2)
  http.HandleFunc("/", Index)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

And using the golang serve mux

```
func main() {
  mux := http.NewServeMux()

  mux.HandleFunc("/page2", Page2)
  mux.HandleFunc("/", Index)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
}
```

Answer (score 55):

The first program uses the [default serve mux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux). It's identical to the more verbose:

```
func main() {
  http.DefaultServeMux.HandleFunc("/page2", Page2)
  http.DefaultServeMux.HandleFunc("/", Index)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", http.DefaultServeMux)
}
```

There's one important difference between the two programs: The first program does not have complete control over the handlers used in the program. There are packages that automatically register with the default serve mux from `init()` functions ([example](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5ec87ba554c2a83cdc188724f815e53fede91b66/src/expvar/expvar.go#L334)). If the program imports one of these packages directly or indirectly, the handlers registered by these handlers will be active in the first program.

The second program has complete control over the handlers used with the server. Any handlers registered with the default serve mux are ignored.

Comment: Why wouldn't HandleFunc, in your provided example, only add it's route to the default serve mux? By your description is sounds as though it is replacing or overriding `first program`'s defined handlers.

Comment: @Brettski The first program in the question adds its handlers to `http.DefaultServeMux` and uses `http.DefaultServeMux` as the root handler for `http.ListenAndServe`. The call to `http.HandleFunc` in the linked example **adds** a handler to `http.DefaultServeMux`.   The call does not replace or override the handlers added by the program.

Comment: Funny, now that I am reading your answer in the morning I see you say the first program will have *access* to (will be active in) the handlers added by the other package. Which. Is the way I assumed it should work. Amazing what a little sleep will do.

Answer (score 5):

Default mux is defined like:

```
var DefaultServeMux = NewServeMux()
```

So there's actually no major difference, unless you want to customize further and need an explicit mux for that (for example chain them for some reason).

But since the default is already allocated there's no need to create another one for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

`ServerMux` is a type which implements the `Handler` interface, all servers have one. In your first example the server just uses the default handler. I don't think there are differences here because the mux returned by `NewServeMux` is going to be the same as the default. It is made available so that you can further customize request handling.

Comment: what type of customization we can do with ServeMux? I could not find any exported fields in it. Also, there are some exported methods but those are for handlers like Handle, HandleFunc, Handler, and ServeHTTP. Could please help me to understand that what type of customization we can do with request?